# Revert all changes to state of a previous commit

Tags: git, version-control

I am working in Git and want to know the best way to revert all of my changes to this Repo back to a specific commit. For example, here is an example of what my log looks like:

```
commit hash#1

commit hash#2

commit hash#3

commit hash#4
```

I am in my `master`  branch and want to revert all changes made to this repo back to commit hash#4. So that means I want to undo the changes that were committed in hash#1,hash#2, and hash#3.

I do NOT want to rewrite/delete history, as this is a public repo. And I do want to (re)commit hash#4 once it has been reverted to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
git reset --hard commit_hash_4
git reset --soft commit_hash_1
```

The first command will reset the working directory and head back to commit_hash_4.  The second command will move the head back to commit_hash_1.  Comitting at this point will preserve linear history but will give you the state of commit_hash_4

Comment: Will I come across any issues when pushing to my remote master branch? The remote master is currently at commit hash#1

Comment: @FillipPeyton no. The end effect of this command is that it will reset your working directory to commit_hash_4 but the commit will occur against commit_hash_1.  It's as if you checked out commit_hash_4 somewhere else and did a copy paste into your current directory.

Comment: @FillipPeyton you should take a look at this explanation of git reset. I constantly visit this page to refresh my knowledge on how this command works and what it's doing under the hood  http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html

Comment: @FillipPeyton also if you are ever worried about how a commit will affect the master, just do a pull, add your commits and view the local history. This is what the pushed master branch will eventually reflect

Comment: Great! Thanks for that info! I read up on `git reset` (http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html) and it definitely illuminated the different options for `reset`.

Answer (score 0):

A great reset overview per (http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html):

> The reset command overwrites these three trees in a specific order,
>   stopping when you tell it to.
>
> 1) Move whatever branch HEAD points to (stop if --soft)
>
> 2) THEN, make the Index look like that (stop here unless --hard)
>
> 3) THEN, make the Working Directory look like that

Just wanted to share for any other users that come across this question.